# How do I post in facebook a big image on a friend's timeline without using sdk feed dialog

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that lets the user create a custom-made greeting card (a big image) and send it to a facebook friend who has their birthday / another occasion on that day. 
I want to allow my user to post the generated greeting card image **on the other friend's timeline**.

- Since feb 2013, developers are not allowed to post on other user's wall using `/feed` (`stream.publish`), the documentation states it is only allowed using the feed dialog (sdk pop-up).

How do I allow a user to post a big image on a friend's timeline from an iOs app without using the sdk's send dialog?

Comment: **Instead** I am thinking of creating an OpenGraph action - **YET**,
posting the open graph action will show it on the sending user's timeline (if `fb:explicitly_shared` or `image[0][user_generated]` are used) - something I do not want. Also, it raises using mention tagging, or message tagging (i.e using "@[uid]" in the message body), both tagging methods are not intended for this exact purpose. Any Ideas on this approeach?

Comment: did try using an OpenGraph action by tagging the addressee of the greeting card, and my OpenGraph im"post"er action received bad user response and my app was blocked by fb from posting more images: the reason is that many users marked "hide from timeline" since the post appeared both in the timeline of the addressee (what we wanted, and what the users expected and want) , but also appeared in the sender's timeline, which many senders did not want or expect, thus pressing "hide from timeline"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the [`Recent Changes`](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/) of Facebook Graph API you can't do this anyway without using the `Feed Dialog` .